# how to add Reflection Permission to IIS or to add it to web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, reflectionpermission

I'm using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) for reading csv files, and all it was ok until I switched from VS dev server to IIS, I get a *"PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired"*, I googled and found that I need to add **Reflection Permission** for this to work, anybody knows how ?

Comment: Can you paste the full exception?

Comment: it was the Load User Profile property from DefaultAppPool AdvanceSettings, I had to set it to true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your asp.net application is probably running in low-trust or medium trust. Reflection permission is in full trust.

You can enable this specific Reflection Permission without going full trust by following this post by Rick Strahl :

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/6344.aspx

Note: it might not work if you're hosted and don't have permissions to override some security settings.

Comment: I don't know, I get this policy exception even when I put Full trust, I'm on a local machine with my own IIS7, Windows 7, VS2008

Comment: it was the Load User Profile property from DefaultAppPool AdvanceSettings, I had to set it to true.