# How do I get rid of the SecurityException error when trying to use Automapper in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, automapper, securityexception

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with NHibernate and I'm trying to use Automapper to hide the Domain objects from the DTO objects sent to the view:

1. ClassLibrary with my Domain (for NHibernate) and DTO objects
2. Class library to make a `SessionFactory` and Factories in my Project

I downloaded AutoMapper to transform Domain objects in DTO and added the code to do this in `Application_Start`.

When I run the app in VisualStudio (by pressing F5) it works fine and my DTOs are mapped into the view.

When I publish this in IIS, I get a security exception:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>(); 
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
```

> System.Security.SecurityException: Failed request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

How do I get Automapper to work without the security exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to run your IIS in full trust in order to have reflection permission, 
look here [reflection permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845797/how-to-add-reflection-permission-to-iis-or-to-add-it-to-web-config)

or here
[set trust level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658%28WS.10%29.aspx)

```
you need this because Automapper uses reflection to emit code o_O
```

Answer (score 13):

Right click on the AutoMapper.dll > select properties > Unblock.

Then restart IIS

Comment: I was already running in full trust and was baffled until I realized that my AutoMapper.dll was "blocked".  Good catch.

Comment: I had to remove the reference from my project and add it back again after unblocking in order to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I unblocked but didn't reset IIS. Works now after iisreset.

Comment: You MUST restart IIS, you can't just unblock and recompile your site.

Answer (score 0):

Unblock the dll (as mentioned by Lee, Right click on the AutoMapper.dll > select properties > Unblock.), and then just recycle the site's app pool. Need not restart IIS.